# Multiple MessageBox Options

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, right-to-left, right-align

It's a silly question but I couldn't find an answer to that :

I'm using a messagebox to display text in hebrew and I need both RTLReading and RightAlign.

I'm currently using :

```
MessageBox.Show(msg, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
```

How can I add MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign?

Comment: Did you try MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading for last parameter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OR them together:
MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading | MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign

Answer (score 7):

Use the OR operator:

```
MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading | MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign
```